# What is the name for this element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you click on "+" below of the element open new texts and the other elements are push down. It's a simple question I know but still valid: how this element is called? I really can't find any name for this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They're most likely using JavaScript, but this is achieved using raw HTML with `details` & `summary` elements. Here is a short implementation:

```css
/* removes the default marker */
details summary::-webkit-details-marker,
details summary::marker {
 display: none; 
 content: "";
}

details {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

summary {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details[open] summary {

  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Some text blablabla +</summary>
  
  <ol>
    <li>asdf 1</li>
    <li>asdf 2</li>
    <li>asdf 3</li>
  </ol>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Some text blablabla +</summary>
  
  <ol>
    <li>asdf 1</li>
    <li>asdf 2</li>
    <li>asdf 3</li>
  </ol>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Some text blablabla +</summary>
  
  <ol>
    <li>asdf 1</li>
    <li>asdf 2</li>
    <li>asdf 3</li>
  </ol>
</details>
```